# Why does Grails' scaffolded create action use params?

Tags: grails, groovy

I created a static scaffolding for my domain class and got a controller for that domain class. The `create` action of the controller looks like:

```
def create() {
    [userInstance: new User(params)]
}
```

I wonder why the line:

```
[userInstance: new User(params)]
```

has been added. Obviously when the `create` action is invoked, there wont be any `params` - so why would this line have been added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Obviously when the `create` action is invoked, there wont be any `params`*

Not necessarily - imagine a situation where you want to pre-populate a couple fields in the form of the create view. You could use:

```
/app/user/create?username=myusername
```

Which would result in the view's `userInstance` having a populated username field for display in the form.

Answer (score 3):

This is fundamentally by Spring, the action is called 'binding' and is the action of tie form elements from one jsp(gsp in this case) to the properties of an object and viceversa.

To tie an object to a form, well, you should create it first, how can ypu tie a null object? it's not possible, that is why the new ClassObject(...)

After that in Groovy we have POGO's, and one feature of POGO's is the ability of initialize them with a map, for example:

```
new User(name:'John',lastname:'Zuñiga')
```

But in this case there's a lil' of groovy magic with that 'params' object. That comes from Groovy Servlets or Groovlets. How can you obtain a param with Java incoming from a form? Well, with `request.getParam("param_name")`, but in this case with Groovy you receive a params object, this params object is a map, a Groovy map...Uhm, one second...

If POGO's in Groovy is able to receive a Map as constructor, and the params object is a Map...maybe...oh coolness I can put that map in the constructor of my object, and after Spring do the binding to the form with this new Object, so this object is travelling in actions from this controller so it comes with the properties populated.

I hope this explanation be clear, if you have questions, I'm here...
Regards

Answer (score 2):

There *could* be params, although in general there wouldn't be.

It allows pre-loading of values, which may be helpful sometimes, including re-displaying the create form.

Comment: Re-displaying of the create form (e.g. when validation errors occur) usually comes through a different action (i.e. `save`) in Grails. However, still a valid situation depending on how someone wants to use the actions.

Comment: @RobHruska Agreed, I think the pre-loading scenario is more likely.